# mongoose subdocuments don't reflect update after Model.findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I've got a schema that looks like:

```
var ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    scrum_master_id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    developers: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Developer'}],
    scrums: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Scrum'}],
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    meta: {
        trello_board_id: String,
        basecamp_url: String
    },
    description: String,
    title: String
  });
```

I can properly send this to my express server and it DOES update properly.  The route in question looks like:

```
.put(jwt.protect, function (req, res) {
     Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}, function (err, project) {
      console.log(project);
      res.json(project);
    });
})
```

The issue I have is that my sub documents like developers aren't updated in the `project` variable being passed into the findByIdAndUpdate callback.  The documents are updated in the database, but just not in the callback of the update function.  How can I refresh those sub documents to reflect what the database now has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) takes an options parameter where you can pass `{new:true}` and it'll return the modified document:

```
Project.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}, {new: true}, function (err, project) {
  console.log(project);
  res.json(project);
});
```

Comment: Sure enough, that's what I'm looking for.  Thanks for pointing out the new flag!